# Laravel: Receive data from ChargeBee

Tags: laravel, chargebee

I managed to create a Customer in ChargeBee but I don't know how to access each of its values.

To receive the information I use the following code, it works perfect for me ...

```
ChargeBee_Environment::configure("mysite-test","test_afhjsfslfsfslk438493sshgeh");
        $result = ChargeBee_Customer::retrieve("16HHGDGJslfksds");
        $customer = $result->customer();
        $card = $result->card();
```

By doing a dd($result) I get the following:

```
ChargeBee_Result {#356 ▼
  -_response: array:1 [▼
    "customer" => array:22 [▼
      "id" => "16HHGDGJslfksds"
      "first_name" => "User"
      "last_name" => "Test"
      "email" => "user@mail.com"
      "phone" => "555667788"
      "auto_collection" => "on"
      "net_term_days" => 0
      "allow_direct_debit" => false
      "created_at" => 1603420880
      "taxability" => "taxable"
      "updated_at" => 1603420880
      "pii_cleared" => "active"
      "resource_version" => 1603420880216
      "deleted" => false
      "object" => "customer"
      "billing_address" => array:6 [▶]
      "card_status" => "no_card"
      "promotional_credits" => 0
      "refundable_credits" => 0
      "excess_payments" => 0
      "unbilled_charges" => 0
      "preferred_currency_code" => "USD"
    ]
  ]
  -_responseObj: array:1 [▼
    "customer" => ChargeBee_Customer {#358 ▶}
  ]
}
```

How can I get for example the id of this Customer??? Which in this case is 16HHGDGJslfksds

Answer (score 0):

You can use this line:

```
$customerId = $result->customer()->id
```